# MediaWiki Remove Top Icons from Mobile frontend

Tags: mediawiki

I am trying to get rid of the the edit, upload and favorite icons from the mobile frontend - anyone have an idea of how to do this?  Been searching around but no luck getting anything to actually work.

Here is an example page:
http://lake.ipiste.fi/index.php?title=SaunaWorld&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile

Answer (score 1):

```
$wgMFPageActions = array();
```

should do it.